# Storm process increasing memory

Tags: memory, apache-storm

I am implementing a distributed algorithm for pagerank estimation using Storm. I have been having memory problems, so I decided to create a dummy implementation that does not explicitly save anything in memory, to determine whether the problem lies in my algorithm or my Storm structure.

Indeed, while the only thing the dummy implementation does is message-passing (a lot of it), the memory of each worker process keeps rising until the pipeline is clogged. I do not understand why this might be happening.

My cluster has 18 machines (some with 8g, some 16g and some 32g of memory). I have set the worker heap size to 6g (-Xmx6g).

My topology is very very simple:
One spout
One bolt (with parallelism).

The bolt receives data from the spout (fieldsGrouping) and also from other tasks of itself.

My message-passing pattern is based on random walks with a certain stopping probability. More specifically:
The spout generates a tuple.
One specific task from the bolt receives this tuple.
Based on a certain probability, this task generates another tuple and emits it again to another task of the same bolt.

I am stuck at this problem for quite a while, so it would be very helpful if someone could help.

Best Regards,
Nick

Comment: Although @MatthiasJSax answer very probably goes to the point, I'm wondering, what kind of input data do you have? Pagerank does not really need a big memory requirement, even without parallelism... Unless you have a really huge input. (I did consider an implementation of pagerank in Storm but for estimating the rank in a sliding window for a stream of data, but I did not do it; if you are trying to solve the streaming problem, I would be curious to know about your approach, and I could share my ideas as well.) Thanks!

Comment: @Irnzcig My input dataset is the friendster social network dataset publicly available through SNAP Stanford. It consists of 65mil nodes and 1.8bil edges. It is quite large actually. My approach is an approximation algorithm (based on random walks) for streaming graph updates. We still haven't published it yet so I am afraid I cannot share the details.

Comment: Ok! Of course that changes the picture. Very interesting project, good luck!

Comment: @Irnzcig Thanks a lot mate, you too.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have a bottleneck in your topology, ie, a bolt receivers more data than in can process. Thus, the bolt's input queue grows over time consuming more and more memory.

You can either increase the parallelism for the "bottleneck bolt" or enable fault-tolerance mechanism which also enables flow-control via limited number of in-flight tuples (https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html). For this, you also need to set "max spout pending" parameter.

Comment: The only thing the bolt in this dummy setup is doing is generate a random double and if it less than 0.8, emit a new tuple to another task of this bolt (i.e. continue the random walk). The parallelism for this bolt is 18, while the spout is a singleton. Each spout tuple, is responsible for the creation of many more tuples further down when the bolt is executed, though.